# Rights for creating SRV records

Tags: .net, active-directory

In a Windows 2003 domain, I would like to create a SRV record programmatically at install time to advertise to clients where my server is located.

Since I do not have the luxury of running as Domain Admin, what kind of permissions do I need to have to create the SRV record?

Generally I'd be using the .NET classes to create the SRV record. I just don't want to go down the wrong architectural path here.

Comment: I cannot help you. However, I'd really appreciate it if you were able to subtly introduce a TexasFlood (or other less obvious) variable in there somewhere.

Comment: One of us is.. talking about something different?

Comment: it's a joke - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevie_Ray_Vaughan (SRV) + http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Flood...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx)-namespace. [Here's blog post](http://www.michaelkbell.com/index.php/2009/01/23/creating-a-dns-entry-in-windows-20003-std-edition-with-c-net/) with a code sample to get you started.

**Edit:** Access Rights-related questions are problably best suited for serverfault.com but the quick answer is that there´s a built-in group in AD called DnsAdmins (in the Users-container). Members of this group have write access to DNS; so adding your service account to that group will allow your app to create SRV-records. (There's also the possibility of setting more explicit rights to DNS but that's a question for you domain admin to decide on. A compromised account which is a member of DnsAdmins can potentially cause a lot of security and reliability-related problems in the domain.)

Comment: It is not a matter of how to do it, rather, in practice, what rights do you need to have to do it? I would like to anticipate deployment issues.